# Jxl did not create the file?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I'm a newbie with Java. Please kindly help.

So I'm using jxl for my project. On my laptop, the Excel file did get created with the data I wrote to it.
But when I tried to use it on my client's computer, the excel was not created. 
I used `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to indicate in which code the program stopped, and it turns out the program stopped at the:

```
workbook.write();
```

My code was like this:

```
File exlFile = new File("C:/Output/Excel Files/Reports.xls");
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFile);
WritableSheet exchangeWrite = workbook.createSheet("EXCHANGE_RATE", 0);

try{

    String sqlTakeExchange    = "select * from R_ExchangeRate";
    PreparedStatement psTakeExchange    = dbConn.prepareStatement(sqlTakeExchange);
    ResultSet rsTakeExchange            = psTakeExchange.executeQuery();

    Label   header = new Label(0, 0, "Ccy", headerFormat());exchangeWrite.addCell(header);
            header = new Label(1, 0, "Rate", headerFormat());exchangeWrite.addCell(header);

    int currentCol  = 1;
    while(rsTakeExchange.next()){
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++){
            for (int col = 1; col < 2; col++){
                Label content = new Label(row, currentCol, rsTakeExchange.getString(row + 1), numberFormat());                            
                exchangeWrite.addCell(content);
            }               
        } 
        currentCol++;
    }
    sheetAutoFitColumns(exchangeWrite);

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.getMessage();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

On my laptop, the excel file contains data that I want with the right format I want.
but on my client computer, it didn't create the file.

I don't know if this helps, but my client uses:
Intel Core 2 duo

Windows XP Professional

Microsoft Office 2007

Java 6 update 26

Ram 1Gb

It's just a PC for any testing. And because my app doesn't require any high spec (just a mini tool to generate excel file from the database). I'm using Java 7 update 51.
Also I have about 4 clients that are using my app. This jxl problem was only showing up on 1 client only, the other 3 did create the excel file.

Any ideas how to solve this? Many thanks

---

After some asking to my senior, it turns out that it's facing a problem with:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spa
ce
```

perhaps i'm gonna tweak the codes.

Comment: try to increase the jvm heap size..If you want to increase your heap space, you can use java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size> on the command line.

Comment: thanks for your advice, Naren!
i'm gonna see the app tomorrow when it runs again on my client's PC